# How to load the crystal report in windows application

Tags: c#

```
ReportDocument rptdoc = new ReportDocument();

rptdoc.Load(@"D:\Tasks\Reports\example.rpt");

rptdoc.Load(Path\\example.rpt");
```

this Path should get from the system.Path is some string variable.
Here in this code I wrote the path directly but i should not write the path as static.It should take from the system.
I am using windows application.

Answer (score 0):

If your reports exist in application path then find application path using

```
String Path = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
Path = System.IO.Path.Combine(Path, "example.rpt");
rptdoc.Load(Path);
```